# Python Legacy - Scapy on Windows (Python 2.4)

Tags: python, legacy, scapy

I have a machine that has Python 2.4, I am unable to upgrade it to a newer edition.
Also, I need to use scapy on this machine (windows)

I have searched for a scapy version for python version less than 2.4 but only found it for UNIX.

Can anyone help me find a scapy version / port to windows?

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the official site, scapy is designed with linux in mind. Everything you should need is [here](https://bytebucket.org/secdev/scapy/wiki/doc/scapy2/installation.html#windows).  But, it looks like some of the utilities that scapy depends on do not support anything older than 2.5.

Can you use py2exe to bundle a different python interpreter with your app? Since you have to stick the app on the machine anyway, why not just give them a single "executable" with a different version of python compiled in.

You could use [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) to install the thing, along with the appropriate dependencies. I.E. libpcap and friends for your version of python and scapy.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Scapy Download and Installation Documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html), Scapy v1.x is your only option if you are running Python 2.4.

To install Scapy v1.x follow the instructions [here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#installing-scapy-v1-2). The documentation does state that Scapy has been designed for unix-like systems, but it does support Windows.